# Is it possible to query Azure SearchServiceClient for a list of document properties

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a process that dynamically create fields on an an Azure "Search service", and a separate site that uses the index.

I would like the site that's searching the index to check for the existence of a column before using it, as using it throws an exception.

So is there a way to query the index for the field definitions?

Comment: How about using [`IndexesOperationsExtensions.Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.indexesoperationsextensions.get?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-search-indexesoperationsextensions-get(microsoft-azure-search-iindexesoperations-system-string-microsoft-azure-search-models-searchrequestoptions)) to get the index definition and then checking the existence of the field in response?

Comment: Apologies @GauravMantri, I didn't see this when I wrote my answer, but that's exactly what I found. If you want to add as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

I found the SearchServiceClient has a Get that fetches the definition

```
            var client = new SearchServiceClient(index.IndexSearchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(index.IndexAdminKey));

            var indexDefinition = await client.Indexes.GetAsync(ProductSearchFields.ProductsIndex);
```